# Access Web UI running in docker container running on remote host

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running CentOS 7 with docker installed on it. I am running docker containers on a custom docker network.

I'm trying to access a web UI from one of those docker containers. The following command works when I attempt to do this on my mac:

```
xhost + $my_ip
docker run -d --rm --name firefox --network myNetwork -e DISPLAY=$my_ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix jess/firefox
```

However, if I just try the simple solution and do

```
ssh -Y remote-host docker run -d --rm --name firefox --network myNetwork -e DISPLAY=$my_ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix jess/firefox
```

It doesn't work; most likely because `remote-host` does not have access to `$my_ip`.

This article got me further https://dzone.com/articles/docker-x11-client-via-ssh by explaining that when you use X11 forwarding with ssh, ssh is actually starting a 'proxy' on the remote machine that listens on the loopback interface of the remote machine.

So I can actually run Firefox from inside a container on a remote host using this dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y firefox dbus && \
    dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/firefox" ]
```

and this docker run command after running `ssh -Y remote-host`:

```
docker run --network host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" firefox
```

Yay! But not quite. If I change from `--network host` to `--network myNetwork` it no longer works. Because, as stated above, ssh is listening on the loopback interface of the host machine, which the docker container no longer has access to.

So it seems like the only way I can get this to work is if I figure out some way to tell ssh to bind to an interface other than loopback when setting up X11 forwarding. Is that possible?

Comment: I wonder if I were to set `GatewayPorts` to yes on the server side `sshd_config` if that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out another way to accomplish my end goal of accessing the web UI of one of the docker containers. I ended up setting up a SOCKS v5 proxy over SSH. This is really intended only for development and debugging purposes and should not be used in a production situation. **I take no responsibility for the security implications of running sshd as root in a docker container. Make sure you understand the consequences of doing this.**

The steps I took are listed below. For this example consider `centosec2` is my EC2 server running CentOS, `myappcontainer` is the name of the container running the application hosting the web UI I am trying to access, and `my-net` is the name of the overlay network that `myappcontainer` is running on.

Requirements:

- Browser that can be configured to connect via a SOCKS v5 proxy. I suggest Firefox with the Add-On FoxyProxy because it makes turning the proxy on and off very easy.
- Docker image that can run `sshd`. I used https://hub.docker.com/r/macropin/sshd/

Steps:

1. Port forward a port from your laptop to the server. In this example **8888** will be the port running the SOCKS proxy from your laptop's perspective and **9696** will be the forwarded port on the server.

   `[user@laptop ~]$ ssh -L 8888:localhost:9696 centosec2 -N`
2. In another shell, open a regular ssh session to the server and then start the `sshd` container. Make sure the `sshd` container is running on the same network as the container running the web UI.

   ```
   [user@laptop ~]$ ssh centosec2
   [user@centosec2 ~]$ docker run --rm -d -p 2222:22 --network my-net -v .ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys macropin/sshd
   ```
3. Once the `sshd` container starts, use the same shell to ssh into the `sshd` container and start a SOCKS proxy on the port being forwarded to your laptop. `-D 9696` tells ssh to start a SOCKS server on port 9696.

   `[user@centosec2 ~]$ ssh -D 9696 -p 2222 root@localhost -N`
4. Your laptop can now access the docker network through the SOCKS proxy running on port 8888. Configure your browser of choice to connect to the internet through a SOCKS v5 proxy running on `localhost:8888`. You should then be able to navigate to the web UI using the hostname of the docker container `http://myappcontainer:8080`

It's a lot of hoops to jump through but it was the easiest way I could figure out how to accomplish this. Hopefully this helps someone else out.